# Transparent background for png image with CSS

Tags: html, css, png, opacity

I wonder is it possible to make transparent background for only 1 color of a png image.
For exemple if my image contains 2 colors red and blue, I wanna make transparent (or change opacity) only the red color.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to use a `img` editor like `adobe illustrator`.

CSS will not do it for you.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with javascript ?

Comment: If it is, I sure have never heard of it. I am "guessing" no.